# How to write an XPath using AND Operator to add multiple spans in a single XPath?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

The page contains a Product name-(3 OF 3) GOLDEN GLOW ( DELUXE ).
The product name has 6 different spans so we want to print the product name "GOLDEN GLOW ( DELUXE )", i.e including the all the spans so I have tried to use the and multiple time inside the [] but it didn't work. Below is the XPath:

```
//*[@class='itemTitleCopy no-mobile' and contains(@class, 'no-mobile') and contains(@class, 'sizeDescriptionTitle no-mobile') contains(@class, 'no-mobile') ]
```

Below is the HTML code:

```
<span class="m-shopping-cart-item-header-number">
   ( 
   <span id="itemNo-1" class="itemNo">3</span>
   of 
   <span id="totalItems-1" class="totalItems">3</span>
   )
   <span class="itemTitleCopy no-mobile" id="itemTitleCopy-1">Golden Glow</span>
   <span class="no-mobile">(</span>
   <span class="sizeDescriptionTitle no-mobile" id="sizeDescriptionTitle-1">Deluxe</span>
   <span class="no-mobile">)</span>
</span>
```

---

### Update

Code trials:

```
WebElement checkoutShippingProdName = new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[@class='m-shopping-cart-item-header-number']"))); 
String shipProdElementHtml = checkoutShippingProdName.getAttribute("innerHTML"); 
String[] shipProdElementHtmlHtmlSplit = shipProdElementHtml.split("span>"); 
String currentProd = shipProdElementHtmlHtmlSplit[shipProdElementHtmlHtmlSplit.length -1]; 
currentProd = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(StringUtils.trim(currentProd)); 
System.out.println("The Product Name is:" + currentProd);
```

Comment: Edit your question with HTML sample, your current XPath, current output, desired output

Comment: I think you are missing and operator before last cotains.

Comment: Post XML which will help us to find the problem.

Comment: I want to prinit the product name i.e Golden Glow ( Deluxe ) ignoring the  (3 of 3) so to get this I am trying to use the AND operatier to write the Xptah //span[@class='itemTitleCopy no-mobile' and contains(@class, 'no-mobile') and contains(@class, 'sizeDescriptionTitle no-mobile')  and contains(@class, 'no-mobile') ]

Comment: And it didn't work i am able to use and operatior only once i.e //span[@class='itemTitleCopy no-mobile' and contains(@class, 'no-mobile') ] till this I am able to identify the Elment but if I use the all the and operator 3 times I am not able to identify elment.

Comment: @user3538483, how is going? Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 2):

```
'//span[@class="totalItems"]/following-sibling::span'
```

should select all `span` nodes after `span` with `class="totalItems"`. There might be different approaches of extracting required text content depends on Selenium binding.

This is Python code to get required output:

```
text = " ".join([span.text for span in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="totalItems"]/following-sibling::span')])
print(text)
#  'Golden Glow(Deluxe)'
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Michael Kay has answered what you need is to use to `or` operator!

You can do this with the `findElements` Selenium.

It should look something like this:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='itemTitleCopy no-mobile' or contains(@class, 'no-mobile') or contains(@class, 'sizeDescriptionTitle no-mobile')]"))
```

This returns a list of `WebElements` now you can iterate through them and join the text to create your desired string of `"GOLDEN GLOW ( DELUXE )"`.

All the credit is to @Michael Kay I just gave you the example...

Comment: Well, you are close. The `(` and `)` seems not getting included.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused about the meaning of `and` and `or`. The `and` operator within a predicate means that both conditions must be true: it's more restrictive, so in general less data will be selected. The `or` operator means either condition must be true: it's more liberal, so more data will be selected.

You seem to be thinking of "and" as meaning "union" - select X and (also select) Y. That's never its meaning in boolean logic.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
//*[@class=('itemTitleCopy no-mobile','sizeDescriptionTitle no-mobile','no-mobile')]
```

Hope it will solve.

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*[@class=('itemTitleCopy no-mobile','sizeDescriptionTitle no-mobile','no-mobile')] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*[@class=('itemTitleCopy no-mobile','sizeDescriptionTitle no-mobile','no-mobile')]' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: This is XPath 2.0 syntax which is not supported by Selenium

Answer (score 0):

To extract the text **Golden Glow ( Deluxe )** you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *XPath*:

  ```
  String myString = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='m-shopping-cart-item-header-number']")).getText();
  String[] parts = myString.split("?<=)");
  System.out.println(parts[1]);
  ```

Comment: Tried this way but not able to print, can you please help me if I am missing anything

Comment: Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status